# c# Raise an event in a web page and consume it in another thread

Tags: c#, .net

I am not sure if this is possible but here is my scenario:

I have a web page that has a button to save changes. When the user clicks the button, I save the data in the button `click event`. However I want to raise an `Event` which that can be consumed in a separate thread.

Is this possible? If so how do I achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Going to need more explanation of what you are wishing to achieve.

Comment: Assuming you mean on the server (not ajax), this is a rather advanced area that you need to be extra careful. Here's a starting point: [Performing Asynchronous Work, or Tasks, in ASP.NET Applications](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tmarq/archive/2010/04/14/performing-asynchronous-work-or-tasks-in-asp-net-applications.aspx). And some info on threading: [ASP.NET Thread Usage on IIS 7.5, IIS 7.0, and IIS 6.0](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tmarq/archive/2007/07/21/asp-net-thread-usage-on-iis-7-0-and-6-0.aspx)

Comment: Ok as an example:

User clicks a button, In the button event I run code to save posted data. I want to raise an event, lets say it is called OnDataSaved.

So in another console application I consume the OnDataSaved event and run some code.

Comment: Is the button on a Windows Forms Application?

Comment: Its not a windows forms application it is a web page.

Comment: Can anyone help with this?